# Build "Boghe" SIP Client Library in Windows phone 8

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.1, sip

I am implementing SIP (voip) in Windows phone 8. So i got a library **Boghe** by  **https://code.google.com/p/boghe/wiki/Building_Boghe_v2_wp8** . I opened project by click on **boghe-wp8.sln** but i got error:-

```
Unsupported
This version of Visual Studio does not have the following project types installed or     does not support them. You can still open these projects in the version of Visual Studio in which they were originally created.
 - BackEnd, "F:\myboghe\boghe\branches\2.0\boghe\winrt\BackEnd\BackEnd.vcxproj"
 - BackEndProxyStub, "F:\myboghe\boghe\branches\2.0\boghe\winrt\BackEndProxyStub\BackEndProxyStub.vcxproj"


Non-functional changes required
Visual Studio will automatically make non-functional changes to the following projects     in order to enable them to open in this version and Visual Studio 2010 SP1. Project behavior will not be impacted.
 - boghe-wp8, "F:\myboghe\boghe\branches\2.0\boghe\boghe-wp8.sln"
```

When i build i got second error:-

```
Error   102 The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\v110\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.    F:\myboghe\boghe\branches\2.0\boghe\winrt\BackEnd\BackEnd.vcxproj   32  3   Agents
```

Please expert help me for build that library. I will be very Appreciate. 
Thank You!

Comment: Windows Phone 8 projects require Visual Studio 2012 and Windows 8 besides the WP8 SDK. It cannot be opened in VS 2010

Comment: SDKyes i have vs2012 , os window8 and WP SDK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u need to make one folder myboghe. Then check out both the folders from their svn in this folder. Run the boghe/2.0/solution file. It will run. If you have any problem get back to me. I will write step by step execution.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the source code

The desktop (XP, Vista, 7, 8) and Mobile (WP8, RT, Surface) share the same base code which means you only need to follow this section if you never checked out the code.

```
Create new directory named myboghe

mkdir myboghe
cd myboghe

Checkout doubango source code into myboghe. Important: The destination directory MUST be named doubango

svn checkout http://doubango.googlecode.com/svn doubango

Checkout Boghe source code into myboghe

svn checkout http://boghe.googlecode.com/svn boghe
```

Building the source code

Building Boghe for Windows Phone 8 is as easy as installing the Windows Phone SDK 8.0, opening myboghe\boghe\branches\2.0\boghe\boghe-wp8.sln and running Boghe-wp8 target project.

Please don't forget to change the CPU type (x86, WIN32, ARM) depending on your target type (Emulator or Device).